# invalid receiver for pointer (alias) type

Tags: go, pointers, methods

It seems quite basics, but I couldn't easily correct the below program
https://play.golang.org/p/8IJn7g0m1As

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct{ value int }
type B *A

func (b B) Print() {
    fmt.Printf("Value: %d\n", b.value)
}

func main() {
    a := &A{1}
    b := new(B(a))
    b.Print()

}
```

```
./prog.go:10:6: invalid receiver type B (B is a pointer type)
./prog.go:16:12: B(a) is not a type
```

For the first, I tried changing the receiver to `func (b *B)` , that didn't work.
For the second, I tried like `&B{a}`, that didn't work either.

`A` is actually a complex struct with mutex in it (a struct generated by `protobuf`), so I need to keep it as a pointer, at the same time need to define additional methods on it, so defining a new type `B`.

Comment: `B` is not an alias here; it is a distinct named type with the same underlying data structure as `*A`, but its own distinct method set, none of which is inherited from `*A`. The error `B(a) is not a type` is correct; it is a type conversion operation, which yields a value, and `new` operates on types, not values. So you could `b := new(B)` or you could `b := B(a)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang Invalid Receiver Type in Method Func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406077/golang-invalid-receiver-type-in-method-func)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is clearly forbidden by the language spec. [Spec: Method declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)

> The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceding the method name. That parameter section must declare a single non-variadic parameter, the receiver. Its type must be a [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) type `T` or a pointer to a defined type `T`. `T` is called the receiver *base type*. **A receiver base type cannot be a pointer or interface type and it must be defined in the same package as the method.**

You can't declare a method with receiver type `*T` where `T` is already a pointer type, and you also cannot add methods for types defined in other packages. The type declaration and the method declaration must be in the same package.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to embed A within a struct for B. You can't declare new types with pointers.

```golang
type A struct{ value int }

// Important diff here:
type B struct{
    *A
}

func (b B) Print() {
    fmt.Printf("Value: %d\n", b.value)
}

func main() {
    a := &A{1}
    b := B{a}
    b.Print()
}
```